# Mute/ignore TS2307 error from TypeScript tsc

Tags: typescript, tsc

Is there a way to mute the TS2307 error from the TypeScript `tsc` compiler?

It makes it really hard to spot real/new errors and warnings as there are *many* TS2307 errors in our codebase.

**Update**:

This error occurs when an external module is `import`ed without its type definition `.d.ts` being present.

I'm aware of `tsd` but for *many* libraries we use, no type definitions exist.

Comment: Is this the duplicate declaration error?

Comment: No, updated question

Comment: suppressing certain errors is still a issue :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This is possible in newer version of TypeScript. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51797689/2300664) from [stsloth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187607/stsloth).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

No, there is not a way to direct the compiler to suppress TS2307. There has been some discussion about it for exactly the reason you describe. For large projects, this becomes a huge barrier to entry.

Details here: [Making JavaScript to TypeScript migration easier : Suppress errors](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4094)

And here: [Find a way to suppress the errors generated by importing modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6114)

What you might be able to do is add a step to your build process that filters the error messages. That, of course, depends on how you are doing your builds.

Answer (score 39):

As of TypeScript 2.6 (released on Oct 31, 2017), now there is [a way to ignore all errors from a specific line](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) using `// @ts-ignore` comments before the target line.

[The mentioned documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) is succinct enough, but to recap:

```
// @ts-ignore
const s : string = false
```

disables error reporting for this line.

However, this should only be used as a last resort when fixing the error or using hacks like `(x as any)` is much more trouble than losing all type checking for a line.

As for specifying certain errors, the current (mid-2018) state is discussed [here, in Design Meeting Notes (2/16/2018) and further comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22011), which is basically

> "no conclusion *yet*"

and strong opposition to introducing this fine tuning.

Answer (score 3):

You might find [`tsc-silent`](https://github.com/evolution-gaming/tsc-silent) useful. Although, ignoring errors you have to [be careful](https://birukov.me/blog/all/tsc-silent.html) and keep in mind that errors code change, and sometimes there are many different problems reported under umbrella error.