# typescript compile code with errors

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a big js (es6) project which I started to migrate to typescript.
First I changed all js files to ts.
Then I executed tsc to compile the project.
tsc outputs A-LOT of errors. I want to fix all of them but it'll take me some time. In this time I still want to project to be compiled as I know it works as expected.

Is there a way to compile while still having errors?
I assume failed imports are a big problem and it'll stop but for sure none of this error exist currently in the project.
I know I can disable checks with compiler option but I'm looking for a simpler way.
Is there? :)

Comment: I would probably ensure all errors are fixed before assuming your code works; some of those errors may prevent the compiler from correctly interpreting your code and there are limited instances where TSC generated JavaScript can be different than you might assume (instances I've seen also usually happen when there are errors).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mute/ignore TS2307 error from TypeScript tsc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880522/mute-ignore-ts2307-error-from-typescript-tsc)

Comment: tsc emits files even though it produces errors (unless you enable the noEmitOnError flag). Doesn't it?

Comment: im using tsc with no options. i checked the compiler options and the noEmitOnError default value is false

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Does it emit files, or not?

Comment: no output files

Comment: Do you have tsconfig file and `noEmitOnError` in it?

Comment: no tsconfig. i can see when i do tsc -t ES2016 --outDir .\output rootFile.ts, this files and its dependencies are generated to js but no one file in the output directory

Comment: I have the opposite problem - tsc *is* generating .js files for .ts files with errors in it!

Answer (score 4):

The current version of TS does this by default - it emits .js code even if there's a non-serious error (e.g. type checking). Perhaps you need:

```
"noEmitOnError": false,`
```

`tsc` will now generate .js files even if there's a compiler error produced.

To *disable* this, i.e. the opposite of what you want we use:

```
"noEmitOnError": true,`
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I'm converting a JS project now. I didn't think updated files were being generated into the output folder because it LOOKED like the console was erroring out, both from the printed tsc errors and from my husky hooks. I tested to see if files were being updated in the build folder and they were. Both js files and ts files with some unresolved type errors were indeed being produced in the output folder. This is without setting noEmitOnError, which should default to false, as a previous comment stated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turns out that if you use the `tsc --build` flag (TypeScript project references), then `noEmitOnError` is forcefully set to `true`, even if you explicitly set it to `false` inside `tsconfig.json`. Apparently this is working as intended, but there is a request to change this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32651