# Nestjs start development server with Typescript errors

Tags: typescript, nestjs

CRA has a flag TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR that enables starting a server even with typescript errors.
What is the equivalent for nestjs? I would like to start a nestjs development server that starts even with typescript compilation errors if possible. These build errors are from the source itself and not from any libraries.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Tried the following to no avail.

```
NODE_ENV=development nest start --debug --watch
```

Which still emitted typescript compilation errors and did not start the server. I know I can go and fix all these issues, but there is quite a bit to fix and would like test other items manually.

Comment: that's typescript stuff. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72187296/5290447

Comment: sadly, adding the no emit flags doesn't change nest's behavior of starting the server when there are build errors